# passing complex input from jquery to Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

What I would like to achieve is to pass parameters from jquery to a Spring Controller. I was successful in passing simple parameter (one string) from jquery to Spring bu how can I do the same with complex data?
For example: in Spring I expect a POJO as input parameter and this POJO has a String property and a List property.
POJO:

```
public class SimplePojo {
  private String one;
  private List<String> two;
  ...
}
```

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String check(@RequestParam(????) SimplePojo input) { ... }
```

JQuery

```
jq.post("/something", ????, function(data){ ... });
```

I put question marks to the places where I have no idea what to write :)
Could you please help me?
Thanks, Viktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In js  :

```
ajax.get('api/checkout_patron/patron_id='+self.patronId())
```

In java :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,value = "/patron_id={patron_id}")
    public @ResponseBody
    Response getPatron(@PathVariable String patron_id){

}
```

Here js request I have mapped using  :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/checkout_patron")
```

on before class declaration.

Here I am using `knockout js`, so I am using this pattern to pass request.

Second Small Example with my technique :

```
            var form={
                sourceName : self.sourceName(),                
                sourceEmail :self.email()
            }
            ajax.post('api/source',JSON.stringify(form)).done(function(response){

            });
```

Here Get data :

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<IWebApiResponse> addBudget(@RequestBody AddBudgetSourceForm form){
       //your code to process data
    }
```

**AddBudgetSourceForm class** :

```
public class AddBudgetSourceForm  {

    private String sourceName;
    private String sourceEmail;

    // getter and setter

}
```

Keep one thing in mind that name of form class and in js `form` data-bind should be same (i.e. left side of parameter in js form that have been stringified).

**UPDATE :**

You can do something like following :

`List<String> var = new ArrayList<>();
var.add(form.getSourcename());
var.add(form.getSourceEmail());`

and yes you can send data like that in json.

If you are sending single data for each thing then don't use `List`.
Instead of that use `List<classname>` and define all required variable in `class` with `getter-setter`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so it means that I should wrap up the data in a json ? for example: {one: something, two: ????}    Actually I don't know how I could the List<String> in the json. Could you please help? thanks

Comment: @Viktor - I have updated the answer, if any problem then post.

Comment: hmmm.. keep smiling.. If you ever get time then look tutorial for MVVM architecture or tell me, I ll post you or mail you..